# How to parse markup from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using a package `react-mentions` to implement a sort of mention like feature that is commonly seen on social media applications.

The resultant text field appears as:

```
 @[admin](user_id:3) hey there! @[test](vendor_id:1) @[project test](project_id:1) asdadstext example
```

I am unfamiliar as to how markup works , how do i process this sentence , so that i can have the resulting data:

```
data = {
user: [{user_id:3}]
vendor: [{vendor_id:1 }]
project: [{project_id:1}]
}
```

Also i wish to ask an additional question to better understand how markup works. Am i able to save the entire string as it is with the markups and when it displays the browser will automatically handle the markups and convert (for example)

```
 @[admin](user:3)
```

to  `admin` ?

Here is an example of a running code:

[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-snyder-k9sof?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you'll get more help if you set something up at `https://codesandbox.io` or stackblitz or a snippet, so people can run it

Comment: alright , its my first time using , ill give it a go

Comment: fyi it's just a markup format used by react-mentions similar to using Markdown syntax.  you can change the template used with the `markup` prop and have it output something different if you wanted to.  You can even change the regex it uses to parse your markup into id and placeholders (it autogenerates a regex based on your markup prop).

Comment: hey @user120242 i have updated the question to include the running code . How would i use regex to parse the markup so that i can store it (within my backend) to be in the shape as mentioned in the question? Sorry if im asking really noob questions

Comment: @User863 gave an example below.  If it were me, I'd try to import their util module and generate one or extract using their functions: https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions/blob/master/src/utils/markupToRegex.js and https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions/blob/master/src/utils/getMentions.js or re-evaluate why I need to extract it like that

Answer (score 0):

Using `matchAll()`

```
/@\[(.*?)]\((.*?):(\d+)\)/g
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GPDdaB/1)

```js
const markup = ' @[admin](user:3) hey there! @[test](vendor:1) @[project test](project:1) asdadstext example'

const parser = (markup) => {
  return [...markup.matchAll(/@\[(.*?)]\((.*?):(\d+)\)/g)]
  .reduce((a, v) => {
    a[v[2]] = (a[v[2]] || []).concat({id: +v[3], username: v[1]})
    return a
  }, {})
}

console.log(parser(markup))
```

Comment: Hey there ! thanks for responding. Its working , however in the scenario where i have 2 users mentions in the sentence , it only picks up the last one . Im thinking that it overrides the array instead of appending it in

Comment: Hey thanks , that aspect of it is worknig perfectly now. However , i realized also that the function does not return back the right key. This above snipper returns back they keys `id:  ___ , username:___` which is only applicable for the user data but not the others

Comment: Would it be possible to extract what is within the brackets to place as keys? i have updated the question. Actually it is only neccessary for me to extract the correct key for the `id` portion

Comment: you can use replace for that

Comment: I am terribly sorry , do you mind updating the answer for that? Im not sure on how to accomplish it